# Unable to acess any files and unable to click on them, everything freezes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-disk

[image]I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and sometimes I am unable to access any files from the desktop or mounted drives. I can't click on them either. I have to open a terminal and use `xdg-open` to open them. Can anyone tell me if this a problem with my laptop (*Lenovo G-50*) or the *OS*? What are potential solutions?

Comment: What do you see in `dmesg` and `sudo journalctl -b` during these periods?

Comment: @ChrisDown I uploaded picture which shows the difference when everything is OK and when it is freezed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the image you uploaded, your disk is dying -- you have a number of unrecoverable read errors in a very short period. You also have an MCE which is a little worrying, it would be good to find out what exactly that's about using `mcelog` (although it may well be root caused to the same disk issues).

That said, no matter what, your disk is definitely dying. You should replace it as soon as you can.